# Does printf() depend on order of format specifiers?

Tags: c, floating-point, double, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    float x=2;
    float y=4;
    printf("\n%d\n%f",x/y,x/y);
    printf("\n%f\n%d",x/y,x/y);
}
```

Output:

```
0 
0.000000
0.500000 
0
```

compiled with gcc 4.4.3
The program exited with error code 12

Comment: I have an urge to mod-down the question - only for the use of "\n" at the beginning of the string. Otherwise, this is why it is always good idea to keep compiler warnings activated.

Comment: @Dummy: agree about the newline, but I haven't been able to get `gcc` to complain about anything accept the lack of properly specified return type on `main`.

Comment: Call me stupid, but what's the matter with newlines at the start of strings?

Comment: @Brian: The idiom in c (and thus inherited by c++) is that newlines go at the *end* unless you have pressing reason to put them t the front. Why? Because K&R did it that way.

Comment: @dmckee Nonsense, you can put a newline anywhere in a string. Hell, you can have multiple newlines interspersed in the string - perfectly good C code.

Comment: @Neil: You can. And then you forget to add the cleanup line like the code above and you leave me with `0dmckee@thorin$ ` for my prompt as well as sticking a wholly unnecessary extra line in the beginning of the output. Put as many newlines in the middle as you need, use leading newlines when it makes a loop cleaner to code, but *prefer ending newlines to leading ones* when they are equivalent.

Comment: @dnckee I routinely embed all sorts of control characters in strings, so we will have to disagree. Certainly K&R never said anything about this. And I can't see how leading and trailing newlines can possibly be equivalent.

Comment: ISO C99 says in section 7.19.2p2 that if a text file doesn't end with a newline, there is no guarantee that the last line appears in the output at all.

Comment: I believe gcc normally screams warnings about passing args that don't match format specifiers to printf. Did you ignore those warnings? Did you suppress them? Don't.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As noted in other answers, this is because of the mismatch between the format string and the type of the argument.

I'll guess that you're using x86 here (based on the observed results).

The arguments are passed on the stack, and `x/y`, although of type `float`, will be passed as a `double` to a varargs function (due to type "promotion" rules).

An `int` is a 32-bit value, and a `double` is a 64-bit value.

In both cases you are passing `x/y` (= 0.5) twice.  The representation of this value, as a 64-bit `double`, is `0x3fe0000000000000`.  As a pair of 32-bit words, it's stored as `0x00000000` (least significant 32 bits) followed by `0x3fe00000` (most significant 32-bits).  So the arguments on the stack, as seen by `printf()`, look like this:

```
0x3fe00000
0x00000000
0x3fe00000
0x00000000  <-- stack pointer
```

In the first of your two cases, the `%d` causes the first 32-bit value, `0x00000000`, to be popped and printed.  The `%f` pops the next two 32-bit values, `0x3fe00000` (least significant 32 bits of 64 bit `double`), followed by `0x00000000` (most significant).  The resulting 64-bit value of `0x000000003fe00000`, interpreted as a `double`, is a very small number.  (If you change the `%f` in the format string to `%g` you'll see that it's almost 0, but not quite).

In the second case, the `%f` correctly pops the first `double`, and the `%d` pops the `0x00000000` half of the second `double`, so it appears to work.

Answer (score 7):

When you say `%d` in the printf format string, you *must* pass an `int` value as the corresponding argument. Otherwise the *behavior is undefined*, meaning that your computer may crash or aliens might knock at your door. Similar for `%f` and `double`.

Comment: Life learned me to always cast all printf arguments like this:
const char*p = "stop"; int i=7; printf("Hello %s %d", (const char*)p, (int)i);

Comment: That's dangerous, too. I prefer to leave away the casts and let the compiler check that the types match. GCC does an excellent job at this. In C, you can never be sure that the `(const char *)` doesn't accidentally convert an `int` to a pointer. Syntactically it would be possible.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Arguments are read from the vararg list to printf in the same order that format specifiers are read.

Both `printf` statements are invalid because you're using a format specifier expecting a int, but you're only giving it a <s>float</s>double.

Comment: But why does its behavior change in both statements?

Comment: @blacktooth: No idea. Compilers do not need to do sensible things when you invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @Billy I told the guy who asked me this question same way. :D He told me that its an interview question!

Comment: @blactooth  Many interviews I've ever gone to, I've re-written their "tests" for them so they were correct, and then told them "no thanks" - a company that asks a bad interview question is a bad one to work for.

Comment: @Billy, to nitpick, you are actually passing a double to the printf function due to default promotion rules.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is undefiend behaviour.  What you are seeing is coincidental; `printf` could write anything.

You must match the exact type when giving `printf` arguments.  You can e.g. cast:

```
printf("\n%d\n%f", (int)(x/y), x/y);
printf("\n%f\n%d", x/y, (int)(x/y));
```

Answer (score 2):

This result is not surprising, in the first %d you passed a double where an integer was expected.

Comment: @Strager: They're all correct answers; I upvoted all of them. Just couldn't think of an additional reason for the others.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format_string_attack

Something related to my question. Supports the answer of Matthew.