# float variables in C

Tags: c, format-specifiers

May be this is a simple question but I am not sure about how float variables are stored in memory and why it is behaving in this way, can someone please explain about the following behavior.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int a = 9/5;
    printf("%f\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

## Output:

```
0.000000
```

I have looked at some information on how float variables are stored in memory, it has stuff about mantissa, exponent and sign. But I am not getting how to relate that here.

Comment: Integer division... Mismatching `printf` format specifier...

Comment: you should check here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673503/using-f-to-print-an-integer-variable

Comment: I don't want fix here, I am aware of that, Just want to know why and what is happening in this case!

Answer (score 6):

```
int a = 9/5;
```

performs integer division and ignores the remainder, so `a` is set to 1. Attempting to print that using `%f` gives undefined behavior, but by chance you got `0.000000` out of it.

Do

```
double a = 9./5.;
```

instead, or print with `%d` if integer division was the desired behavior. (`float` would also work, but `a` will be promoted to `double` when passed to `printf`, so there's no reason not to use `double`.)

Comment: Quotient would come into a, not the remainder.

Comment: In this way, a should be set to 1 is it nt?

Comment: @ManikSidana: yes, so it *ignores the remainder*.

Comment: 9/5 is 1 not 0.. that might lead to a downvote.

Comment: @Ram: yes, 1, sorry. The fact that it seems to be 0 is because you're passing a wrongly-typed argument for the `%f` format specifier.

Comment: @Aniket: thinko on my part, fixed. But it's not important what the result of the division is; passing an `int` to `printf` when a `double` is expected is UB.

Comment: @ larsmans. Remainder is obtained using %, not /

Comment: @ManikSidana: I know that. I'm saying the remainder is *ignored*, so only the quotient is returned.

Comment: Are you sure that after C99 there is float promotion to double in function argument passing?

Comment: @codewarrior: there is in the case of varargs.

Answer (score 1):

It is an undefined behaviour in C. Use `%d` format specifier instead of `%f`.

[Does printf() depend on order of format specifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383425/does-printf-depend-on-order-of-format-specifiers) gives you detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is an Undefined Behaviour.

You are using float format specifier (`%f`) to print an int (`a`). You should use `%d` to see correct output.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brief analysis of your code:

```
int a = 9/5; // 9/5 = 1.8, but since you are doing integer division and storing the value in an integer it will store 1.
printf("%f\n", a);//Using incorrect format specifiers with respect to datatypes, will cause undefined behavior

printf("%d\n",a);//This should print 1. And correct.
```

Or if you want the float:

instead of `int` use `float` :

```
   float a=9.0f/5;//This will store 1.800000f
   //float a=9/5 will store 1.000000 not, 1.8 because of integer divison 
   printf("%f\n",a); //This will print 1.800000
```

Also do read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008 on how floating points work.

Clarification about integer division:

C99:
**6.5.5 Multiplicative operators**

`6` When integers are divided, the result of the `/` operator is the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded.<sup>88)</sup> If the quotient `a/b` is representable, the expression `(a/b)*b + a%b` shall equal `a`

<sup>88)</sup> This is often called ‘‘truncation toward zero’’.

Comment: 9/5 makes an integer division. You probably meant 9.0/5.0f

Comment: 9/5 is not 1.8, it is 1, since 9 is int and 5 is int. It doesn't matter whether you attempt to store the 1 into an int or a float, it doesn't affect the calculation.

Comment: P.S: About Multiplicative operators

    6 When integers are divided, `the result of the / operator is the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded`.88) If the quotient a/b is representable, the expression (a/b)*b + a%b shall equal a. And I must say, the integer is result, due to the truncation towards zero.

Answer (score -1):

Just assuming that your division should result in a fraction in normal math won't magically make it a float.

```
int a = 9/5;
```

You need to use

```
float a = 9.0/5;
```

First you need the right data type i.e. float (or better yet double for higher precision) to store a float.

Secondly, if you are dividing two integers i.e. 9 and 5, it will simply follow integer division i.e. only store the integer part of division and discard the rest. To avoid that i have added .0 after 9. This would force compiler to implicitly covert into float and do the division.

Regarding your mentioning of why it is printing 0, it is already mentioned that trying %f on integer is undefined behavior. Technically, a float is 4 bytes containing 3 byte number and 1 byte exponent and these are combined to generate the resultant value.

Comment: 9/5 is actually 1. So that's not what he is looking for. Why is floating point to integer conversion having a value of 0.00 for this particular problem

Comment: 9/5 is actually 1 it is obvious. I pasted it from question and added the correct version under it to clarify the difference. Where did i say he was looking for 1??

Comment: Strictly speaking you should either write `float a = 9.0f / 5.0f` or `double a = 9.0 / 5.0`. As you wrote this example, you enforce the calculation to be done on a double, which you then truncate into a float. You make the code more ineffective for no gain. If you are lucky the compiler might be smart enough to optimize, but don't count on it.

Comment: That's correct but very 'strictly speaking'. Considering the person asking the question. Preference of double or float should stay out of the way. As a teacher, i have always learned to illustrate but not complicate the topic. Even if it is demoted to float, it achieves the goal of generating the floating point value albeit with lesser precision. I certainly not see this as a reason for down vote or consider above a better explanation. But every one has his own opinions :)